# TinyBF to Brainf*** converter

Tags: code-golf, brainfuck

We have a Brainf*** to TinyBF converter, but not the other way around, so here's one.

### Rules:

- Your interpreter must take a valid TinyBF program, on one line, and it must output the corresponding BrainF*** program, on one line, with optional trailing whitespace/newline. No leading whitespace is allowed
- The input may or may not contain characters that are not any of the four TinyBF characters. If so, you must print all of these characters in the same spots.
- An answer will be accepted on April 1st (not joking), based on some obscure criteria I will use (jk ;) I will accept the shortest program that does not cheat by the following rules)
- No 0-byte or 1-byte solutions, because it ruins the fun if you make (or there is) a programming language just for this purpose)

### Test Cases

---

Input 1: `+++++>+++++=>=|>>+=>>+|=>|>+=>+|` (Computes 5 (byte 1) + 5 (byte 2) = 10 (byte 3))
Output 1: `+++++>+++++<[>>+<<-]>[>+<-]`

Input 2: `+++>++++Hi+++:P+=>=|>|>+>+=>>&&+|=>>|=>>=+!!>>=+|>>>+|` (Computes 3 (byte 1) * 8 (byte 2) = 24 (byte 3))
Output 2: `+++>++++Hi+++:P+<[>[>+>+<<&&-]>>[<<+!!>>-]<<<-]`

Comment: Will there ever be I/O commands?

Comment: No, because TinyBF doesn't have IO commands.

Comment: That's incorrect; `==` is brainfuck's `.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Python 2, 106 bytes

```
a=0
r=''
for c in input():a=[a,~a][c=='='];r+={'+':'+-','>':'><','|':'[]'}.get(c,c)[a%-2]*(c!='=')
print r
```

Implements the TinyBF specification as found [here](https://esolangs.org/wiki/TinyBF). [Try it online](http://ideone.com/fork/Uiilad). Improvements were made using techniques from [@Dica's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73290/45941). Requires quoted string input.

Comment: This works for all of my test cases! Good job.

Comment: You can save 5 bytes with `r+=b.get(c,c+c)[a]*(c!='=')`. You can also make the for loop one line to save 3 more. You can inline the dict to save 4 more. Inlining `input()` is another 4.

Comment: Also, you need to either use `raw_input` or switch to Python 3 and take the byte penalty for `print`. Right now I get `SyntaxError: invalid syntax`.

Comment: @Mergo I based my answer on yours but I guess it's okay because the modifications are heavy, let me know if you want me to remove it

Comment: @MorganThrapp The input is quoted, so it works for 2. Taking quoted string input is allowed per a meta post that I can't find right now because I'm on mobile.

Comment: @Mego Oh, huh, did not know that. I would've assumed quoted input was disallowed.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Found it: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/7633/string-input-with-or-without

Answer (score 3):

## Python 3, 97 bytes

This script is based on [@Mego's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/73254/51264)

```
a=0
for c in input():a-=c=='=';print({'+':'+-','>':'><','|':'[]'}.get(c,c)[a%-2]*(c!='='),end='')
```

Comment: I think this is too similar to Mego's answer and should have been suggested as an optimization in a comment.

Comment: Although this is shorter, I accepted Mego's answer because your answer is too similar to Mego's an seems like an optimization rather than a distinct answer.